# How do multiple arrow operators in series work in Perl?

Tags: perl

I ran across a piece of Perl code I wasn't sure how to interpret today. Specifically, the line `$lookup -> {$chr} -> {$start} = $end` as I am not sure how multiple infix dereference operators work in series.

The input file contains tab-delimited chromosome names `($chr)`, start positions `($start)`, and end positions `($end)` on each line. I get that the author is creating a hash table where `$chr` maps to arrays with `$start` values corresponding to each chromosome, but I can't establish exactly what he is trying to accomplish with the next line. Any insight would be much appreciated.

```
my $hash;
my $lookup;
if (defined $bed_file) {
    open(FILE, $bed_file);
    while (my $line = <FILE>) {
        chomp $line;
        my ($chr, $start, $end) = split(/\t/, $line);
        push(@{$hash -> {$chr}}, $start);
        $lookup -> {$chr} -> {$start} = $end;
    }
    close(FILE);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$lookup -> {$chr} -> {$start} = $end
```

`$lookup` is (being treated as) a pointer to a hash of hashes.  `$chr` is the first level key, the value is another hash pointer.  `$start` is the second level key, whose value is `$end`.

This code is relying on [autovivification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autovivification).  Although `$lookup` is never initialized to anything, when working with pointers in Perl, if you pretend/believe that a structure exists, it exists.  Ditto for the `$hash` variable (a hash of arrays.)

Another Perl feature, not employed here, is *arrow collapsing* such that arrows between indexes (of either sort) are optional.  So this code can also read:

```
$lookup->{$chr}{$start} = $end
```

possibly better revealing the two level hash structure.

`$lookup` and `$hash` at the top level are parallel hashes, in that their first level keys are the same.  The `$hash` structure appears to be an optimization as it could be computed from `$lookup`:

```
keys(%{$lookup->{$chr}})
```

vs.

```
@{$hash->{$chr}}
```

the difference being that `$hash` would preserve the file order of the `$start` values and `$lookup` would not.

Answer (score 1):

By saying `$lookup->{$chr}->{$start} = $end` (the second arrow is optional, you may also write `$lookup->{$chr}{$start} = $end`), the `$lookup` scalar is turned into a reference to a hash that has chromosome names as keys.

Each entry in the hash that `$lookup` is a reference to is in turn a hash reference to a hash with the start position as key and the end position as value.

You may easily investigate the data structure after the loop by adding

```
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper($lookup);
```

You will see something like

```
$VAR1 = {
          'chr2' => {
                      '1234' => 5678
                    },
          'chr1' => {
                      '1234' => 5678
                    }
        };
```

This tells you that `$lookup` is (loosely speaking) a "hash of hashes".